# Cognos change datasource of existing package

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a package that was exported from a Cognos 10.2.1. development server and imported into a new server.  I now need to change the data source on that package on the new server but am unable to find where to do this.

Note, I cannot just add a new data source with the same name as the one currently specified in the package, because a data source with that name is already defined on the new server, but is not the data source that I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty method would be to export the package, open the file in a text editor, search for the name of connection, confirm that the reference is to the old connection, and replace the text with the new connection name.

Almost all objects in Cognos are stored as XML which makes them amenable to this method.